# I am unable to set back data to ckeditor instance which I fetched from it and stored in database?

Tags: javascript, html, django, ckeditor

I have a Django web app which has various instances of ck-editor instances on a web page.By using on blur event I am saving whole of data of the instance in the database -

```
{% for editor in editors %}
   CKEDITOR.appendTo("{{editor.ck_id}}" ,
    {
        on: {
            blur: function(event){
                var data = event.editor.getData();
                console.log("data of {{editor.ck_id}} is " + data);

                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "/editor/save/",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        content : data,
                        content_id : "{{editor.ck_id}}"

                    },
                    dataType: "html"
                });
            }
        }

    }
    // "{{editor.data}}"
    );
    CKEDITOR.instances['{{editor.ck_id}}'].insertHtml("{{editor.data}}");
```

Here ck_id and data are the two database fields of ckeditors.Now suppose I write this on one instance of ckeditor -

```
Tony Stark
```

When I lose focus on that instance then on blur event is fired and I use 'getData()' to get the html data of that instance.

```
<p>Tony Stark</p>
```

is saved into the database.On the python interpreter now when I fetch editor's data it shows -

```
<p>Tony Stark</p>
```

which is obvious.
Now When I re start the server and set the data of every ck-editor instance again then this exception is raised -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I know why this is happening - due to this -

```
CKEDITOR.instances['ck_1'].insertHtml("&lt;p&gt;Tony Stark&lt;/p&gt;
");
```

The data which I sent by fetching from database was -

```
<p>Tony Stark</p>
```

and it somehow got converted to above mentioned text with illegal tokens.I have tried to use setData() but with no result. Do I need to encode/decode this HTML or something?

Now my question is how to again reset data to a ck-editor instance which I fetched from it and stored in database. I have posted this question on several forums but many people have got no clue of what I am asking?

Is there anyone here who has tried to do same thing and have succeeded in it?
Thanks

PS: Adrian Ghiuta solution seems to be working but there is just problem. When the editor is loaded first time then in google chrome's debugger inserted line is seen as -

```
"<p>Tony Stark</p>"
```

which is rendered due to line "{{editor.data|safe}}".But when I change my editor's content to just

```
Tony
```

then in database

```
<p>Tony</p>
```

is being saved but when I restart the server it does not render and throws this error

```
Unexpected ILLEGAL TOKEN
```

due to this -

```
"<p>Tony</p>
"
```

Here ending double quotes are in the next line.But during initial data loading it was on the same line.Might this be causing be any problem?
Because my chrome console shows error at that position.

I will add some images to show the condition.

Initial loading - 
[image]

Initial console - 
[image]

Editor after editing -

[image]

Error being shown after restarting server and reloading editors -

[image]

Console - 
[image]

You can see how error is thrown at line where double quotes are at the next line.Do I to escape html or something?

Sorry for my naivety but I do not have much command over HTML.